# Using value from directive provided to an element as child's input

Tags: angular, components, directive

I have a Template with a directive like this:

```
<section my-directive>
    <wrapper-component [visible]="{{-myDirective.visibility-}}"
</section>
```

*my-directive* holds a variable *visibility* which is a boolean. This variable should now be passed to the [visible] input of the wrapper-component.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Using a template is no passable way because of other things in this case.

Comment: Maybe `#myDir=[my-directive]` and then `myDir.visibility`?

Comment: You can use exportAs: 'myDirective' and define the template variable as #myDir="myDirective"